# The StringVar() returns PY_VAR0 instead of a string

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to set a text into my label with this code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Hello Tkinter")
        self.label_text = tk.StringVar()
        self.label_text.set("Choose One")
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=self.label_text)
        self.label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1, padx=100, pady=30)
        hello_button = tk.Button(self, text="Say Hello", command=self.say_hello)
        hello_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(20, 0), pady=(0, 20))
        goodbye_button = tk.Button(self, text="Say Goodbye", command=self.say_goodbye)
        goodbye_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=(0, 20), pady=(0, 20))
        
    def say_hello(self):
        self.label_text.set("Hello World")

    def say_goodbye(self):
        self.label_text.set("Goodbye! \n (Closing in 2 seconds)")
        self.after(2000, self.destroy)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Window()
    window.mainloop()
```

But I get this as a result:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yes, an instance of `StringVar` is not a string. There are many questions on this site that are similar. Search for PY_VAR0 on this site.

Comment: ^ so you need: `textvariable=self.label_text` and not `text=self.label_text`

Comment: More specifically, you need `self.label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.label_text)`.

Comment: Yes it works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is

```
 self.label = tk.Label(self, text=self.label_text)
```

you need to add .get() like this one:

```
 self.label = tk.Label(self, text=self.label_text.get())
```

other wise you get PY_VARO as default